# Stream read returning empty in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, node-webkit

I am using express to create a webservice that will read string data from a stream, and respond to the HTTP POST request with that value. Here is the code for the `S3Store.js` file that defines the `readFileFromS3(.)` function:

**S3Store.js**

```
S3Store.prototype.readFileFromS3 = function(filename, callback) {
var readConfig = {
    'Bucket': 'shubham-test',
    'Key': filename
};
var readStream = this.s3.getObject(readConfig).createReadStream();
var allData = '';

readStream.on('data', function(data) {
    //data = Buffer.concat([allData, data]);
    data = allData + data;
    console.log("data: " + data);
});

readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    callback(err, null);
});
```

Now, if I call this method from a terminal like this:

```
s3Instance.readFileFromS3('123.json', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I see the appropriate string for `data` logged to the console. However, when I call the same method from inside one of the `routes` in express for `HTTP POST` requests, the service responds with a value of `data` set to empty string. Code for the POST request:

```
router.post('/resolve', function(req, res) {
    var commandJson = req.body;

    var appId = commandJson['appId'];
    var command = commandJson['text'];

    if (appId == undefined || command == undefined) {
        res.status(400).send("Malformed Request: appId: " + appId + ", command: " + command);
    };

    s3Store.readFileFromS3('123.json', function(err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Why does it return an empty string when calling the `readFileFromS3(.)` from the HTTP POST method and not when I ran the same method directly from the node console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging the data but you're not passing anything to the completion callback (see below for some more explanation):

```
S3Store.prototype.readFileFromS3 = function(filename, callback) {
  var readConfig = {
      'Bucket': 'shubham-test',
      'Key': filename
  };
  var readStream = this.s3.getObject(readConfig).createReadStream();
  var allData = [];

  // Keep collecting data.
  readStream.on('data', function(data) {
    allData.push(data);
  });

  // Done reading, concatenate and pass to completion callback.
  readStream.on('end', function() {
    callback(null, Buffer.concat(allData));
  });

  // Handle any stream errors.
  readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    callback(err, null);
  });
};
```

I took the liberty to rewrite the data collection to use Buffer's instead of strings, but this obviously isn't a requirement.

The `callback` argument is a completion function, meant to be called when either reading the S3 stream is done, or when it has thrown an error. The error handling was already in place, but not the part where you would call back when all the data from the stream was read, which is why I added the `end` handler.

At that point, the `readStream` is exhausted (everything from it has been read into `allData`), and you call the completion callback when the collected data *as second argument*.

The common idiom throughout Node is that completion callbacks take (at least) two arguments: the first is either an error, or `null` when there aren't errors, and the second is the data you want to pass back to the caller (in your case, the anonymous function in your route handler that calls `res.send()`).

Comment: I used your version of readFileFromS3() method and it works perfectly fine. I am, however, new to Nodejs - can you elaborate on "but you're not passing anything to the completion callback"?

Comment: @Shubham.Shukla I added some more explanation.